# Convolution with Gaussian

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

Let $f, g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)$ (Schwartz class function), $\delta_0$ ([dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)).

Consider  distribution as follows:
 $$G(x, y)= f(x)g(x)\delta_0(y)-f(y)g(y)\delta_0(x), \ (x, y\in \mathbb R)$$

Let $h(x,y)= e^{-(x^2+y^2)}.$

My Question is:

> Can we expect  that $G\ast h \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^2)$?

where $\ast$ denotes the convolution.

Comment: Do you mean $G\ast h$?

Comment: @Marco: Yes. Thanks. I'll correct the typo.

Comment: Also, could you please be more precise about how the distribution $G$ acts on Schwarz functions? For example for a writing like $f(x)\delta_0(y)$ you mean that $\left\langle f(x)\delta_0(y), \phi(x,y)\right\rangle=?$

Comment: BTW it is a bit strange to formulate the question as you did instead of replacing $fg$ by a single Schwartz function. This is because every Schwartz function can be written as $fg$ for some Schwartz functions $f,g$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I'd say if $T \in S', \varphi \in S$ then $f \mapsto f \ast (\varphi T)$ is a continuous map $S \to S$. Not sure by which argument. When replacing $S$ by $C^\infty_c$ it is obvious.

Comment: @reuns: Which part of what I said are you trying to correct/improve?

Comment: I think this is the abstract formulation of OP's question.

Comment: I don't think it works. If the OP's question is a particular case of your abstract question then you should be able to tell me what is $T,\phi,f$ using the OP's notations.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam  $T(x,y) = \delta(y), \varphi(x,y) = f(x)g(x)e^{-y^2}$

Comment: When you do the pointwise product $\varphi T$ the $e^{-y^2}$ disappears.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do the explicit computation:
$$
(G\ast h)(x,y)=\int\int G(u,v)h(x-u,y-v)dudv
$$
$$
=\int\int f(u)g(u)\delta(v)h(x-u,y-v)dudv-
\int\int f(v)g(v)\delta(u)h(x-u,y-v)dudv
$$
$$
=\int f(u)g(u)h(x-u,y)du-\int f(v)g(v)h(x,y-v)dv=\gamma(y)((fg)\ast\gamma)(x)-
\gamma(x)((fg)\ast\gamma)(y)
$$
where $\gamma(z)=e^{-z^2}$ which is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. The latter is stable by product and convolution. Moreover, the product of a Schwartz function in $x$ and a Schwartz function in $y$ is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. So the result is not only in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ but in fact in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.